# can I force Outlook 2007 rule to print first page only?

Tags: printing, outlook

I have set up a rule to quite simply print out an email when received from a certain address (Amazon sales) - The idea being that as orders come in, they are auto printed and waiting to be packed.

However the amazon emails require 2 pages.

under the Rules menu in Outlook, the option is simply "Print" but no further print preferences are available.

Is there a way to get it to print the first page only? a script possibly?

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook Object Model does not porvide any fine controls over the print functionality. As a workaround, you can export the message as a DOC file (MailItem.saveAs), then programmatically load it in Word and use the Word Obejct Model to print it.